# Rails Model method self. vs plain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When looking at methods in Rails models, sometimes I see `self.method_name` and sometimes just a `method_name`. What's the difference and what is the guide to know when to use `self.` and when not to?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

self.method_name indicates a class method; method_name indicates an instance method.

You can read a lot more about class and instance methods [at this blog post](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) or, if you'd prefer something a bit more official, the [Programming Ruby class section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes).

Answer (score 43):

1) When applied to method definitions, 'self.' will make it a class method, while plain will be an instance method.

2) When applied to attributes in a model, it's important to always use the self when changing an attribute, but you won't need it otherwise.

so for example:

```
def some_method
 self.name = new_value # correct
 name = new_value # will not change the attribute
end
```

Comment: even better than upstair answer.

Comment: Point 2) was driving me nuts. Thanks!